# Updating in datastore not working in GAE 1.9.0

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-api-php-client

We have a PHP application running on GAE. It connects to Cloud Datastore using the Google PHP library (v0.6.7).

Google introduced in the last days a new version of App Engine, v1.9.0 (not oficially released), which apparently was running fine, just as 1.8.9 was. However, we have been experiencing some issues related to Cloud Datastore. Sometimes, all the operations regarding to entities updating are just ignored. All the queries used to retrieve information work perfectly, however if we want to create a new entity of update any property, no action is performed. I have been checking for some errors in the response returned by the Cloud Api, but there is no errors or warnings at all.

This situation happened for the first time the 31st of January, and it is also happening today. It started to fail at 3am (GMT +1) and  according to the instance log, at the same time the latency times of all the requests suffered an important increase (from 1-3 secs to 5-10 secs). The first time after a few hours the system started to work properly again, but  now this problem is lasting much more.

Has anyone experienced anything similar?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Reads (lookups, GQLQueries) work just fine, but commits don't work at all.

Comment: are you programming in GAE using PHP too?

Comment: Yes. It's really strange because the API doesn't return an error. All that's returned is a mutationResult array without any index updates.

Comment: That exactly what is happening to me. I guess you are using the google_api_php_client library for the communication with Datastore. Same version?

Comment: I tried different versions of the library but it didn't matter.

Comment: I've reported the problem in the GAE issue tracker. Maybe you can add more information about it. https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10557

Comment: I can't access your link and the issue id 10557 is missing form the issue tracker.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46783/discussion-between-javier-o-and-paul)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the report, we're investigating the issue now.

Update: We've addressed the issue. Please join the Google Cloud Datastore downtime notify mailing list for future updates.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/gcd-downtime-notify/sNXCFJYFNQU

For future reports about production issues, please refer to the [Contact support](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/support) section of our documentation.